# Difference between declaring methods in .h file and in .m file specifying @interface and @end

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I just don't understand why some guys declare the methods in the .m file. Can't those declarations just go in the .h file instead?? Here's what I see mostly:

```
//myClass.h

#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface myClass: UIViewController
{

}

@end
```

And the implementation (.m) part:

```
//myClass.m

#import "myClass.h"

@interface myClass

//declare some methods here

@end

@implementation myClass

//the actual implementation

@end
```

Is there any difference when the methods are declared this way?? Also, "@private" methods can be declared in myClass.h itself, can't they?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Difference between @interface definition in .h and .m file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3967187/difference-between-interface-definition-in-h-and-m-file)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The code you have posted both doesn't compile and isn't equivalent to declaring methods in the header.

The purpose of the header is to provide a set of declarations that other classes can import. They can't import your implementation file, because that will create duplicate definitions.

As bbum said, what you're probably seeing is *private method declarations* in the implementation file. These aren't intended to be used outside the class, so they're declared in the implementation file. The feature is called a class extension:

```
//MyClass.h

#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface MyClass: UIViewController

// Declare methods that other classes should call here

@end

//MyClass.m

#import "MyClass.h"

@interface MyClass () // <--- NOTE THE PARENTHESES HERE

// Declare methods that only this class should be using here

@end

@implementation MyClass

// Define all your methods here

@end
```

And no, you can't declare "`@private` methods" in the header, or anywhere else. There's no such thing in Objective-C. The `@private` access specifier only applies to variables.

Answer (score 5):

It's about keeping the separation between the public and the private interfaces to your class.

Being able to declare methods, properties and iVars in the implementation file is a clear indicator to you of what you can do and use from within the class and what can be done from outside the class.

You can also redeclare properties. For instance:

**in .h**

```
@property (readonly, copy) NSString *aString;
```

**in .m**

```
@property (readwrite, copy) NSString *aString;
```

so from within your class you can treat the property as readwrite, but externally, the property is readonly.

Answer (score 2):

- `MyClass`, not `myClass`;  classes start with capital letters.

I would be surprised if that code compiles at all.  If in the .m, you were to say:

```
@interface MyClass()
@end
```

Then that'd be a class extension, which has been discussed many times on SO.   As it is, you are declaring a conflicting `@interface` for `MyClass` and the compiler should complain.

Comment: Well, classes don't HAVE to start with a cap -- it's standard convention (which should be observed) but not enforced by the compiler or any other Xcode/iOS component.

Comment: If you don't start classes with a capital letter and you were to submit said code as a coding sample to just about any decent company, they'd quite likely not hire you.   Your choice. ;)

Answer (score 0):

I've several times declared internal classes (differently named from the main class) in the .m file.  These would be classes used by the main class that the .m contains (and which was declared in the .h).  This way the internal class is "private", plus, with it all in one file, it's easier to read and update while working on the main class implementation.

Comment: Suggestion;  When declaring internal classes, add a suffix like `__` to the class name.  This makes it entirely obvious when an internal class is involved in a backtrace, etc.   I use internal classes all the time -- very useful -- and will generally use a class instead of a structure, too.