# Two interfaces in *.h and *.m files

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, class-extensions

Sorry for my English, let speak from my heart :)
In one project which I work, I noticed an interesting moment.

In *.h file declared interface:

```
@interface FrontViewController : UIViewController
...
@end
```

And in *.m file I found another interface.

```
@interface FrontViewController()

// Private Properties:
@property (retain, nonatomic) UIPanGestureRecognizer *navigationBarPanGestureRecognizer;

// Private Methods:
- (IBAction)pushExample:(id)sender;

@end

@implementation FrontViewController
...
@end
```

Why is it needed? And what's the point? -I think that this is for convenience. Yes?

Comment: Because I programmed in ObjectiveC++ and C++ also has head files and implementation files.

Comment: This has been answered many times. Here's one: [Difference between @interface definition in .h and .m file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3967187/difference-between-interface-definition-in-h-and-m-file)

Comment: Sorry, I don't find before post question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That's a class extension. It's usually used to declare private methods and properties for a class.

Read about it [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/cocoa/conceptual/objectivec/Chapters/ocCategories.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30001163-CH20-SW1).

Comment: Hmm, except I can not specify private methods in an .h file? Or if I specify in .m file private methods, I get additional plus in check on compilation for implement privite methods specified in .m file?

Comment: The header is the publicly available class definition.

Answer (score 3):

That is a class extension.  It allows you to declare "private" methods and properties for a class, even if you don't have access to the source.  The primary use is to not expose those methods as part of the interface.  Unlike most languages, these methods are run-time discoverable, so the value of these is in the IDE auto-completion, not in preventing consumers of your class from calling the hidden methods, which is why I put private in quotes.  It is possible to simply define methods in the implementation without a declaration, but then they must be implemented above any places they are used. Declaring them as an extension prevents this problem.

If an extension is named, then it becomes a category which can be used to distribute your class implementation among several files.