# What's the logic of putting @interface in .m file?

Tags: objective-c

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Difference between @interface definition in .h and .m file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3967187/difference-between-interface-definition-in-h-and-m-file)
>   [What is the @interface declaration in .m files used for in iOS 5 projects?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9751057/what-is-the-interface-declaration-in-m-files-used-for-in-ios-5-projects)

I've seen code like this:

```
// In Header.h
@interface Header{}
@end

// In Header.m
@interface Header()
@end
```

My questions are:

1. What's the difference in putting it in 2 files?
2. Why put {} after class name in ".h" file and why "()" in ".m" file?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
@interface MyClass(){
    NSInteger aInt;

}
@property(nonatomic,strong) NSString *name;
@end
```

is a [class extension](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/cocoa/conceptual/objectivec/chapters/occategories.html)

with modern compilers this is a great way, to decrale methods, ivars and properties only for private use in the class MyClass.

Class extensions have to be declared in the main implementation file (not in a category).

So you can hide implementation details from the header file, they are private.

Comment: thanks, really solved the big puzzle for me.

Comment: You can also create implementation properties, which I find are more useful than class extensions.

Comment: To use ivars in extensions, you have to use the llvm 3+. GCC is not aware of this syntax

Comment: @RichardJ.RossIII - what's implementation properties thing?  One more thing, I have seen code doing this, interface Header{} property(nonatomic,readonly) BOOL sessionDidExpire; end and then in the .m file, property (nonatomic,readwrite) BOOL sessionDidExpire; what's this thing?

Comment: indeed with LLVM it is true, you can declare ivars at `@implementation MyClass { NSInteger aInt;}` to. but I like to separate it into a class extension.

Comment: @itsaboutcode excuse me, I mean implementation iVars, however, I use ARC so much there really isn't much difference between the two now.

Comment: it is a public readonly property, while from inside the class u can also write to it — very handy.

Answer (score 3):

This has become a common practice for declaring "private" properties/methods for a given class.  By declaring them in an anonymous class extension inside the .m, these properties/methods are not exposed to consuming objects.