# Error when compiling: No visible @interface declares the selector

Tags: objective-c, uiviewcontroller, interface, visibility

In one class I have the following
AlertEditorContainerViewController.m

```
    #import "AlertEditorContainerViewController.h"

    @interface AlertEditorContainerViewController ()
    -(void)swapViewControllers;
    @end

    @implementation AlertEditorContainerViewController

    @synthesize currentSegueIdentifier;
    @synthesize segIndex;

   - (void)swapViewControllers
   {
       self.currentSegueIdentifier = ([self.currentSegueIdentifier  isEqual: SegueIdentifierFirst]) ? SegueIdentifierSecond : SegueIdentifierFirst;
       [self performSegueWithIdentifier:self.currentSegueIdentifier sender:nil];
   }
    @end
```

The in another class I try to call it
AlertEditorViewController.h

```
    @interface AlertEditorViewController : UIViewController <UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource>
    { 
          AlertEditorContainerViewController              *containerViewController;

     }
```

AlertEditorViewController.h
       #import "AlertEditorViewController.h"

```
    @implementation AlertEditorViewController
    - (IBAction)segmentSwitchValueChanged:(id)sender
    {
          [containerViewController swapViewControllers];    
    }
    @end
```

This gives the error "No visible @interface for AlertEditorContainerViewController declares the selector  swapViewControllers'

I have looked up all of the other similar queries and they all seem to point at typos etc which I can't find in my code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Declare `-(void)swapViewControllers` in your `AlertEditorContainerViewController.h` file, not your `.m` file.

For information on this problem, you'll want to check out [this Stack Overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9751057/what-is-the-empty-interface-declaration-in-m-files-used-for), but in short, by declaring the method within the `@interface` block located in your `.m` file, you're effectively making it a private method (inaccessible by other implementation files). From the link:

> The interface section in the implementation file allows you to declare variables, properties, and methods that are private, meaning that they won't be seen by other classes.

The compiler knows it's there within the scope of that particular file, but other files can't access or even see that method as being defined.